# ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string--- Converting Timestamp column to EST

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

```
SELECT   
    FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP(THC.HOUR,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24'), 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York',
    TD.NAME,   
    SUM(THC.MW) AS MW_SUM  
FROM
    TD, THC 
WHERE   
    THC.HOUR >=  CAST(FROM_TZ(CAST(TO_DATE('1-JUL-2022 00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24') AS TIMESTAMP), 'America/New_York') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS DATE) 
    AND THC.HOUR <=  CAST(FROM_TZ(CAST(TO_DATE('1-AUG-2023 00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24') AS TIMESTAMP), 'America/New_York') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS DATE)
GROUP BY  
    FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP(THC.HOUR,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24'), 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York',
    TD.NAME,
```

I have the following piece of code, which I am trying to convert a timestamp ("HOUR") column to the proper time zone accounting for DST. I get a "Date format picture..." error if I run it as shown in the question. Also using casting the column as in the where clause However will give me the right results but it would take very very long time, I was wondering if anyone has an idea.

Thank you very much

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: you have this tagged as sqldeveloper .. does the query run fine in pure sql*plus? or does it just occur via sql devveloper ?

Comment: I don't have sql plus to try it.